# Test trigger who call apex method who call future method

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, governorlimits, httprequest

I'm struggling to test this situation, I'm new to salesforce and I need to integrate SF with our website, whenever someone update/create/delete account on SF I should send that information to our website.
I created three separated trigger:

```
trigger beforeDelete on Account (before Delete){
  SendNotification.process(trigger.new, 'delete');
}


trigger afterUpdate on Account (after update) {
  SendNotification.process(trigger.new, 'update');
}

trigger afterInsert on Account (after insert) {
  SendNotification.process(trigger.new, 'create');
}
```

This class has two methods, one creates a JSON from List that I got from a trigger, and another one sends that JSON.

```
public with sharing class SendNotification {

    public static void process(List<SObject> arrayOfObjects, String action, String objectName){
        sendToApp(createJSON(arrayOfObjects, action));
    }

    public static String createJSON(List<SObject> arrayOfObjects, String action){
        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName('values'); 
        gen.writeStartArray();
        for( integer i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.size(); i++){
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField('id', arrayOfObjects[i].Id);
            gen.writeStringField('Name', arrayOfObjects[i].Name);
            gen.writeStringField('action', action);
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
        gen.writeEndObject();
        String pretty = gen.getAsString();

        return pretty;
    }

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void sendToApp(String body) {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

        request.setEndpoint('https://our_web/our_api');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setBody(body);

        if ( !Test.isRunningTest() ){
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

            if(response.getStatusCode() != 200){
                System.debug('ERROR');
                System.debug('Res returned');
                System.debug(response.toString()); 
            }else {
                System.debug('Res returned');
                System.debug(response.toString()); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my test class:

```
    @isTest
public with sharing class SendNotificationTest{

    @istest static void json(){
        Account acc= new Account(Name='Test Account');
        insert acc;
        List<SObject> myList = new List<SObject>();
        myList.add(acc);

        string s = SendNotification.createJSON(myList, 'create');
        s = s.replaceAll('\n', '').replaceAll('\r','');
        s = s.deleteWhitespace();

        string expected='{"values":[{"id":"'+acc.Id+'","Name":"'acc.Name'","action":"create"}]}';
        System.assertEquals(expected,s);
    }

    @istest static void deleteTrigger(){
        Account acc= new Account(Name='Test Account');
        insert acc;

        Test.startTest();
        delete acc;
        Test.stopTest();
        System.debug('This is sistem getCallouts delete');
        System.debug(Limits.getCallouts());
        System.assertEquals(Limits.getFutureCalls(), 1);
    }

    @istest static void updateTrigger(){
        Account acc= new Account(Name='Test Account');
        insert acc;

        Test.startTest();
        update acc;
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(Limits.getFutureCalls(), 1);
    }

    @isTest static void testPostCallout() {
        Notifier.sendNotification('1');
        System.assertEquals(Limits.getFutureCalls(), 1);
    }
}
```

The first test, JSON pass successfully and the last one(testPostCallout).

But I have a problem with other tests:

`System.assertEquals(Limits.getFutureCalls(), 1);` it's not 1, it looks like when `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` finished, they don't restart `Limits.getFutureCalls()`, other tests fails, because `Limits.getFutureCalls()` is greater then 1.

If I try Limits.getCallouts() is allways 0, why is that?

How can I restart Limits? Is this a good way to test triggers?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using Change Data Capture rather than using custom code to achieve this objective?

Comment: You should pretty much never use `Test.isRunningTest`, and definitely not in this way. Read up on `HttpMock`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two vital changes you need to make if you wish to cover your callout.

1. Never use `Test.isRunningTest`. Use mocks instead here.
2. Create a synchronous method you call from your `@future` method.

**Mocking**

First of all, remove your check on `Test.isRunningTest` and just run everything inside that block unconditionally. Then in your tests, you'll need to set a few different mocks to cover your various status code conditions.

```
class CalloutMock extends HttpCalloutMock
{
    final Integer statusCode;
    HttpCalloutMock(Integer statusCode)
    {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request)
    {
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(statusCode);
        // set any other attributes as desired
        return response;
    }
}
@IsTest static void testMyCallout_200()
{
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new CalloutMock(200));

    // set up data as necessary

    Test.startTest();
        // call method
        // cache any limits checks here
    Test.stopTest();

    // assert as necessary
}
// add tests for other status codes
```

**Synchronous Method**

Creating a synchronous method which your `@future` method calls allows you to actually inspect limits consumption.

```
@future
public static void makeAsyndhronousCallout(String payload)
{
    makeSynchronousCallout(payload);
}
public static void makeSynchronousCallout(String payload)
{
    // actual logic here
}
```

Once restructured in this way, you can have your trigger tests verify you consume a future call, and have a test against the synchronous method which verifies you actually consume a callout.

---

Apart from the above, I recommend one other change. While it is not vital, it is much more convenient, includes a notable boost to performance, and makes it easier to avoid null pointers and some other errors.

When working with JSON, I highly recommend you to **work with serialization/deserialization rather than using generators/parsers**. You just need to create a model class to serialize from.

```
class BulkPayload
{
    final List<SinglePayload> values;
    public BulkPayload(List<SObject> records, String action)
    {
        values = new List<SinglePayload>();
        for (SObject record : records)
            values.add(new SinglePayload(record, action));
    }
}
class SinglePayload
{
    final String id, name, action;
    Payload(SObject record, String action)
    {
        this.id = record.Id;
        this.name = (String)record.get('Name');
        this.action = action;
    }
}
```

Now your entire `createJSON` method can be simplified to:

```
return JSON.serialize(new BulkPayload(arrayOfObjects, action));
```

Comment: @adrianLasrson 
Hey, thank you very much, I will try to implement those changes.
Once again thanks for the help :)